# CakePHP install with Composer version 3.1.*

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

My problem is that not all server run PHP 5.6 or above.
So I need use a older version of CakePHP 3.1.* that support PHP 5.5.*/5.4.* .

The problem is the Composer install solution:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:3.1.9 demo
```

Gives me an error:

> Could not find package cakephp/app with version 3.1.9

I have tried other version (3.1.11/12/10) without success.
Is there a way or do I need to download the releases manually from GitHub every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cakephp/app` is a different repository from `cakephp/cakephp`. So it follows it's own versioning.

`cakephp/app` is a template/skeleton that you can use to create your app. While cakephp/cakephp is the main core.

Check below for the cakephp/app:

- https://github.com/cakephp/app
- https://github.com/cakephp/app/releases

I guess you could use the version `3.1.2` of cakephp/app that allows you to have PHP **>= 5.4**

https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.1.2/composer.json#L8

Comment: Ok, but how i can use this version with composer?

Comment: You already wrote the command above ``composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:3.1.2 demo``. Isn't this what you are asking?

Comment: @gmponos The "problem" is that the app template uses a version constraint of `~3.1` for `cakephp/cakephp`, which means [**`>= 3.1 && < 4.0.0`**](http://semver.mwl.be/#?package=cakephp%2Fcakephp&version=~3.1&minimum-stability=stable), so the OP would need to change that one to something more restrictive, like for example [**`~3.1.0`**](http://semver.mwl.be/#?package=cakephp%2Fcakephp&version=~3.1.0&minimum-stability=stable).

Comment: I thought that composer will resolve this automatically and install until ``cakephp/cakephp 3.1.12`` because his version of PHP is not 5.6. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.12/composer.json#L21. Am I wrong?